# Really basic Samba set-up not working

Tags: debian, samba, webmin

Background: I had a Debian server running a Samba share, and it played nicely with everyone: Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, Windows 7, Windows 10, Android 8 through whatever is current, even XP (for testing purposes).

One of the services (Plex) on that server was problematic, so I set up another Debian server with the same storage devices, and set up the services I want. So far, all of the services work, except for Samba.

I figured I mucked up the config some how, so I copied line by line the config file from the old server to the new server, and this had no change.

I know it's a problem on the server, since it's the same for all the clients (Linux, Windows, Android, etc)

Win10 and Mint are both giving me the same generic error: `Permission Denied`

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Samba has these nifty logs - one for each client, but, when I try to read those logs, they're blank and all read as 0kb.

It seems like a simple thing that should be working... What the heck do I do now?

Any advice is appreciated; thanks in advance!

(BTW in case it matters, I tried the first time using Webmin, then just the config files in /etc when Webmin didn't work)

Output from `grep -Ev '^\s*[#;]|^$' /etc/samba/smb.conf` as requested in the comments (I changed the username to my given name and I'm working with a test share that will be deleted once I have this issue corrected)

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        dns proxy = no
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        syslog = 0
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        server role = standalone server
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        obey pam restrictions = yes
        unix password sync = yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        pam password change = yes
        map to guest = bad user
        usershare allow guests = yes
        unix extensions = no
[test]  
        comment = test
        writeable = yes
        path = /home/tony/test
        valid users = tony
```

```
ps -ef | grep -E 'smbd|nmbd|winbind|sssd'
root       42538       1  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
root       42540   42538  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
root       42541   42538  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
root       42549   42538  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
root       42551       1  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/nmbd --foreground --no-process-group
root       90058   35763  0 16:18 pts/1    00:00:00 grep -E smbd|nmbd|winbind|sssd
```

Comment: Hi roaima, I added that info to my post. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the username to my given name and I'm working with a test share that will be deleted once I have this issue corrected.

Comment: Well, the log files for clients. For example log.1.2.3.4 is empty and ls -ahl shows it's size as zero. The logs for nmbd and smbd are populated, but nothing significant as far as I can tell. Actually, when I looked at the time stamps, it looks like the client logs weren't even touched today - their time stamps are from last week. So, maybe there's some problem that broke smbd to the point it won't write logs anymore? very confusing :-(

Comment: Used the following to uninstall/reinstall, added the test share, same results: empty log files...................

sudo apt-get purge samba samba-common

sudo rm -rf /etc/samba/ /etc/default/samba

sudo apt-get install samba

Comment: root       42538       1  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
root       42540   42538  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
root       42541   42538  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
root       42549   42538  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
root       42551       1  0 14:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/nmbd --foreground --no-process-group
root       90058   35763  0 16:18 pts/1    00:00:00 grep -E smbd|nmbd|winbind|sssd

Comment: Added to querstion

Comment: Have you created a `tony` user account _inside Samba_? (Not just `/etc/passwd`, but actually inside Samba itself too)

Comment: OMG! I knew it was something simple that I missed!!!! Thank you so much @roaima  I asses using the smbpasswd command with the -a switch. It's interesting to me that in all the other implementations I've set up I actually used Webmin to make it faster, and never had to do this step before because I selected the "sync" option. New versions (of either Samba, Webmin, or Debian broke this I guess) Thank you so much again! I was ready to give up!

Comment: Great. I've written an answer for you that incorporates my comment suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a standalone Samba system you need to add users to its own password database. (This is distinct from the UNIX/Linux password database, typically `/etc/passwd`.)

You do this with `smbpasswd`, so in your case

```
smbpasswd -a tony    # Add "tony" to the Samba users database
```